# Issue with ADT : Java heap space

Tags: android, eclipse

while i'm coding some stuff on one of xml files.a message suddenly shown up:

```
register.xml: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:97)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:233)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:782)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:457)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:86)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)

Session Data: 
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
```

i do some search on it,i don't understand what's the meaning of that issue,i guess it's belong to luck of memory (but i have 4Go in RAM) & i must put some commands on exlipse.ini, but i don't know how i can do it. 
any one can help me with it.
thanks
PS:sorry if my english is not well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must increase eclipse heap size.
Try to append this to eclipse.ini file:

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Are you using very large images when composing layout?